# Error when trying to do anything with Heroku. Rails 3.1

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been trying to use heroku with my rails app. I've gem install heroku and listed it in my gemfile, but everytime I try to do anything with it I keep getting this error...

```
    /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:755:in  `split': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:755:in `load_from_file'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:838:in `block in <class:Types>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:838:in `each'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:838:in `<class:Types>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:578:in `<module:MIME>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mime-types-1.17.1/lib/mime/types.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/heroku-2.11.0/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/heroku-2.11.0/lib/heroku.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/heroku-2.11.0/bin/heroku:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I'm new to rails so would appreciate help if anybody knows whats gone wrong. I've googled it but can't seem to find the same problem.

These are the list of gems I currently have installed incase that may be the cause:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
actionpack (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
activemodel (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
activerecord (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
activeresource (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
activesupport (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
addressable (2.2.6)
ansi (1.3.0)
arel (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21, 1.0.18)
coffee-rails (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
daemons (1.1.4)
devise (1.4.9, 1.4.8)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
execjs (1.2.9, 1.2.4)
heroku (2.11.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.16, 1.0.14, 1.0.13)
json (1.6.1)
launchy (2.0.5)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.1, 1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
pg (0.11.0)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.5, 1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-cache (1.1, 1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.0)
railties (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rdoc (3.11, 3.9.4)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sass (3.1.10, 3.1.7)
sass-rails (3.1.4, 3.1.2, 3.1.0)
sprockets (2.0.3, 2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
thin (1.2.11)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.3, 0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.30, 0.3.29)
uglifier (1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2)
warden (1.0.6)
```

All the other gems work fine though. It's just the Heroku one that throws up an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had done a gem update + bundle update and that was what was messing it up.

I've uninstalled mime-types 1.17.1 and all seems to be working ok now. I had to uninstall it though. Even when I set the app to use version 1.16 it still came up with the same errors when I tried to do anything with Heroku.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Padrino 0.10.5, using .16 fixes it for now... Thx! :)

Comment: Good news!.. It's fixed in 1.17.2 :) https://github.com/halostatue/mime-types/commit/963373e67535a4a475cc1f3c3d522adf56d1fb34

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include Heroku into your gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with mime-types 1.17.2, just released. I could not reproduce the issue on Mac OS X, but the problem was fairly easy to fix.